# How to load number of rows based on date and time selected without refreshing the page using php?

Tags: javascript, php

When I click `count` it should display the numbers registered based on the schedule and selected date.

[image]

My table looks like this:

```
ID     DATE            TIME        NAME
1      2017-01-15      AM          AAA AAA 
2      2017-01-15      AM          BBBB BBBB    
3      2017-01-16      PM          DCCD VDFD    
4      2017-01-18      AM          FG FGFG    
5      2017-01-19      PM          SDF FG    
6      2017-01-19      PM          DFG DFG
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: use ajax for getting the data without refreshing......

Comment: Please share what code you have tried...so we can help. People can not provide you complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following code you can change it according to your requirement i am providing you guidience
We have one textInput for date and 2 radio buttons for selection of Am and Pm
and a div with id count_result for showing the ajax result

```
<input type ="text" class="date" value="date('Y-m-d')" />
    <input type = "radio" class="option" value="1" checked="checked" />AM
    <input type = "radio" class="option" value="2" />PM
 <input type="button" id="count" value="Count" />
 <div id="count_result"></div>
```

Now here is your js code

```
    $('body').on('click','#count',function(){
       var date = $('.date').val();
       var time= 'AM';
       if($('input[class*="option"]:checked').val()==2)
         time= 'PM';
       $.ajax({
         type : 'html',
         dataType : 'get/post',///send request get or post///
         url : 'count.php',//////request sending to page count.php//////
         data : {date:date,time:time},//sending variable to count.php page////
         success : function(data){
          $('#count_result').html(data);
},
        error : function(){
        console.log("Error");
}
});

});
```

in your count.php

```
    $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
     $time = $_REQUEST['time'];
    $qry = mysql_query("select count(`*`) as `total_count` from table where `date`='$date' and `time`='$time'")
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
echo $row['total_count'];
```

it will show total count in count_result div, i hope it will help you